# Show alert after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a button which calls stored procedure and binds gridview.
I found a code on stackoverflow for top alert bar like this:

```
function topBar(message) {
        var alert = $('<div id="alert">' + message + '</div>');
        $(document.body).append(alert);
        var $alert = $('#alert');
        if ($alert.length) {
            var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                $alert.trigger('click');
            }, 10000);
            $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 500).click(function () {
                window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
            });
        }
    }
```

Then in my button I try to call this function like this:

```
Dim script As String = String.Format("topBar({0});", Server.HtmlEncode("Successfully Inserted"))
        Response.Write(script) 'Or even like this
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "topBar", script, True)
```

But it simply does not work.
Can you guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I always sort this type of problems with supplying a Boolean Property whether javascript should fire a piece of script or not. For example :

```
public bool IsDone { get; set; }
```

> Sorry that the code is in C#

This is a property on code behind file. When I need to fire the javascript method, I simply make this true.

What I do on the aspx page is as follows :

```
<script>    

    if(<%= IsDone.ToString().ToLower() %>) { 
        alert("Done!");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I get this error: "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks" My codebehind says: Public Dim IsDone As Boolean = True :(

Comment: put your script code block inside `<div runat="server"></div>` if it doesn't need to be on the head section. Any change?

Comment: view source of your rendered html. How does your JavaScript code look like?

Comment: Like this: <div id="Div1">
            <script>

                if ( < %= IsDone.ToString().ToLower() % > )
                {
                    alert("Done!");
                }

</script>
            </div>